# package manager for git

Tags: git, package-managers

Assume that I have some git repo on my machine that I cloned from github and that I only want to use this program. I don't want to make some change and push them.  I want to keep these programs up to date. I can cd into every repo and `git pull origin master`

Is there a way to do this automatically, like I would do with an `aptitude update` / `aptitude upgrade` ?

Comment: *man git buldpackage*

Comment: You could just create a shell script that called the Git commands for you…?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look into this tool?

https://myrepos.branchable.com

I believe it could address your use case.

Here is an excerpt of its [description](https://packages.debian.org/stable/myrepos):

> The mr(1) command can checkout, update, or perform other actions on  a
>   set of repositories as if they were one combined respository. It 
>   supports any combination of git, svn, mercurial, bzr, darcs, cvs,
>   vcsh,  fossil, and veracity repositories, and support for other
>   version control  systems can easily be added. (There are extensions
>   adding support for unison  and git-svn, among others.)
>
> It is extremely configurable via simple shell scripting. [...]

FYI it can be installed this way:

```
cd ~/forge/git   # for example
git clone git://myrepos.branchable.com/ myrepos && cd myrepos
make && sudo make install PREFIX=/usr/local
```

but according to the [doc](https://myrepos.branchable.com/install/) it is also available as a a package in most GNU/Linux distributions.

Additional info regarding the configuration of `mr` can be obtained by doing `mr help` or `man mr`.

Hoping this helps